# IIS 10 System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Access denied

Tags: identityserver3

I'm current using this sample as my test bed.
IdentityServer3.Samples/source/MembershipReboot/

I've assigned the correct permissions and read several other posts about this problem but I still get access denied.

My IIS app is running under applicationpoolidentity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use IIS Local instead of Express to have more control with security. I hope you will get success with this following steps:

1. Install the certificate in the Personal directory of the Current User. ([Help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb950259(v=bts.10).aspx))
2. Assign a dedicated application pool to the IdSrv3 virtual application or website. ([Help](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add))
3. Assign your user as the identity of the dedicated application pool. ([Help](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities))

The user that run IIS must have the read rights on the certificates store where you put it. ApplicationPoolIdentity does not have this rights.